# Can the WP plugin handle unions and type punning?

Tags: frama-c

I am working with a type punning example and am wondering if WP or another plugin can handle this. So far, I couldn't really find anything on WP and unions, but they seem to be supported.

Here is an example snippet:

```
float uint32_reg_to_float(uint32_t val) {
    union {
        uint32_t ui32;
        float    f;
    } u;

    u.ui32 = val;
    return u.f;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, WP will only be able to deal with programs that use unions in the most restricted sense, i.e. which always read the exact same field that has been written to the last time the union was updated (in which case, from a purely logical point of view, you can more or less see all the fields as distinct variables). It's probably not what you meant by type punning, though...

On the other hand, Eva shouldn't have any problem with such unions, with the obvious caveat that an abstract bit pattern that would result in a small integer interval might be much more imprecise when interpreted as float and vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the hint about Eva!

Comment: Actually, conversion of part of a float bit-pattern into an (integer) interval is maximally precise in the current Eva implementation. (Taking into account the imprecision introduced by the interval representations on both sides.) Some imprecisions remain in the converse direction (integer -> float).